# Тормозит отправка данных сенсора в фоновом режиме

Tags: android, android-service

Создал сервис, который считывает показатели датчиков устройства, отправляет в обработчик(MagnetHelper), и в цикле отправляет обработанные данные по udp протоколу. Собственно, в сервис я это всё перенёс, т.к. в фоновом режиме данное дело, вполне предсказуемо - тормозит, пакеты отправляются где-то каждые 500мс, что неуместно. Но и после этого ничего не изменилось: пока приложение открыто - отправляется нормально, как только уходит в фон - появляется большая задержка.

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;

/**
 * Created by Vyacheslav on 20.07.2018.
 */

public class ServiceSender extends IntentService implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mSensor;
    private Sensor aSensor;
    private MagnetHelper MG;
    private MyPreferences Prefs;

    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private InetAddress address;
    private String Port;
    private boolean running = true;


    public ServiceSender(String name) {
        super(name);

    }

    public ServiceSender() {
        super("ServiceSender");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Prefs = new MyPreferences();
        MG = new MagnetHelper(Prefs);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        aSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, aSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.107");
            Port = "4545";
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Gdx.app.log("EXCEPTION", "Socket");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        double Axes[];
        running = true;
        while(running) {
            Axes = MG.getAxes();
            float Acc[] = MG.getAcc();
            sendEcho(Acc[0], Acc[1], Acc[2], Axes[0], Axes[1], Axes[2]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            if(!Prefs.isLowPassFilter()) {
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, MG.getmMagnetometerReading(),0, MG.getmMagnetometerReading().length);
            } else {
                MG.filterMagnet(event.values.clone());
            }
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            if(!Prefs.isLowPassFilter()) {
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, MG.getmAccelerometerReading(), 0, MG.getmAccelerometerReading().length);
            } else {
                MG.filterAcc(event.values.clone());
            }
        }
        mSensorManager.getRotationMatrix(MG.getmRotationMatrix(), null,
                MG.getmAccelerometerReading(), MG.getmMagnetometerReading());
    }

    public int sendEcho(double x, double y, double z, double yaw, double pitch, double roll) {

        ....

        DatagramPacket packet
                = new DatagramPacket(bb.array(), bb.array().length, address, Integer.parseInt(Port));
        try {
            socket.send(packet);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Gdx.app.log("EXEPTION", "Send");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, aSensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```